# Is it possible to update MS Flow Approval Status using Rest API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, approval-process, power-automate

I need to create an approval process which will need the approver to add comments as well as upload file. For achieving this, I plan to create a custom form with required set of controls.

I've been trying to update the approval status on the item by updating `OData__ModerationStatus` & `OData__ModerationComments` to get the flow moving further. But what happens is, it updates only the `OData__ModerationComments` and not the `OData__ModerationStatus`.

If somebody can help on how to update the status of approval flow using Rest API to get the Flow continue further, it would be great. Any pointers to do it through custom logic also would be of great help.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I may not have the full picture here, and I apologize if you've already considered this - but if you are using Flow anyway, then why not just use the "Set content approval status" action instead of trying to update via Rest API?

This action allows you to set the approval status as required (Submit, Approved, Rejected) without fiddling with the OData__ModerationStatus field.  This action also allows you to log whatever you like in the "Comments" field at the same time.

[image]